# Как использовать cuda для класса python?

Tags: python, cuda

Я использую cuda  для распознавания людей с помощью библиотеки OpenPose. (python)

У меня есть небольшая проблема. Поиск людей происходит на GPU с помощью cuda, а мой класс, который должен помечать найденных людей и отслеживать их перемещение, запускается на CPU.

Очевидно, что CPU в несколько раз медленнее GPU, поэтому слежение происходит некорректно. Подскажите, как я могу запускать функции своего класса не на CPU, а на GPU?

Я использую Ubuntu 16.04, GTX 1080 Ti, CUDA 9.2.

```
class CentroidTracker():
def __init__(self, maxDisappeared=20):
    self.nextObjectID = 0
    self.objects = OrderedDict()
    self.disappeared = OrderedDict()
    self.countPhoto = OrderedDict()
    self.maxDisappeared = maxDisappeared


def register(self, centroid):
    self.objects[self.nextObjectID] = centroid
    self.disappeared[self.nextObjectID] = 0
    self.nextObjectID += 1
    return "Ok"
```

Comment: Задача совсем не тривиальна, как может показаться на первый взгляд. Я бы начинал [отсюда](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Ray. 
В нём Вы сможете указать, что субъекту требуются процессоры или графические процессоры в декораторе.

```
@ray.remote(num_cpus=2, num_gpus=1)
    class GPUActor(object):
    pass
```

Надо будет переделать Ваши классы python в ray actors. (Это быстро и просто)
При использовании графических процессоров Ray автоматически устанавливает переменную окружения CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES для actor после его создания. Actor будет иметь доступ к списку идентификаторов графических процессоров, через которые ему разрешено использовать ray.get_gpu_ids(). Это список целых чисел, как [], или [1], или .[2, 5, 6]

Когда GPUActor экземпляр создан, он будет размещен на узле, который имеет по крайней мере 1 графический процессор, и этот графический процессор будет зарезервирован для actor на время его существования (даже если actor не выполняет задачи). Ресурсы GPU будут освобождены, когда actor завершит работу.

Дополнителную информацию Вы можете посмотреть [Тут](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actors.html) 
В разделе ***Resources with Actors***

Так же стоит отметить, что, если у Вас только один графический процессор, то придётся делить его на все actors по типу `@ray.remote(num_gpus=0.25)`.
Правда заранее придётся убедится, что он не забит чем-либо другим, например, Вашей программой для поиска людей. Или уже исправить соотношение с запасом.